# Using mongoose-autopopulate but disable it for the specific nested field

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm using [mongoose-autopopulate](https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/plugins/autopopulate#it-requires-an-option-to-work-with-lean) to populate to all fields from mongo. For the performance issue, how can I disable for the specific nested field, for example:

```js
var SchemaA = new Schema({
    field1: String,
 .......
 fieldB : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SchemaB', autopopulate: true }
});

var SchemaB = new Schema({
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
 .......
});

var SchemaC = new Schema({
    field1: String,
 .......
 fieldD : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SchemaD', autopopulate: true }
});

var SchemaD = new Schema({
    field1: String,
 .......
 fieldB : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SchemaB', autopopulate: true }
});
```

When I query SchemaA: populate SchemaB is fine

When I query SchemaC: populate SchemaD is fine, but I don't want to populate SchemaB

How can I achieve it?